# Projection Proof (Linear Transformation)

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I'm tyring to proof this theorem regarding projections:

Given a projection (linear transformation) $P:V\rightarrow V$ over $W$ and a given vector $v \in V$

i need to proof $v \in W \Leftrightarrow P(v)=v $

I tried using $P^2=P$ and also the face that $Im(P)=W$ but got stuck,

thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $P$ is the projection over $W$ the range of $P$ is $W$.

If $y$ belongs to $W$ then $y=Px$ for some $x$ so $Py=P^{2}x=Px=y$.

Conversely if $Py=y$ the $y$ belongs to the range of $P$ so $y \in W$.

Comment: got you thank you :)

Comment: Someone has been downvoting most of my answers without assigning any reason.  Fine. Let them  enjoy.  I will continue my work of helping students learn Math.